# How to backup MySQL database on Linux server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database

Please I want to backup my database on a Linux server and I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take backup of all databases

   ```
   mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all-databases.sql
   enter password:
   ```
2. Take backup of Single databases

   ```
   mysqldump -u root -p databases > databases.sql
   enter password:
   ```
3. Backup Remote MySQL Database

   ```
   mysqldump -h Remote_Ip -u root -p databases > databases.sql
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It backup successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax of the command

```
mysqldump -u [username] –p[password] [database_name] > [dump_file.sql]
```

`[username]`: A valid MySQL username.
`[password]`: A valid MySQL password for the user.
`[database_name]`: A valid Database name you want to take backup.
`[dump_file.sql]`: The name of backup dump file you want to generate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of backupping a database: running or down.

- down: shut down the database, backup all the files (typically `/var/lib/mysql`)
- running: `mysqldump` to dump the database.

If you just copy the files without shutting down, there is no guarantee that your backup is a valid database (might  work most of the time though, as long as the log-files are copied last)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the ways of backup explicitly.